# Plotting two graphs in one in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
     X             Y        
[1,] 0.0000000  0.2534477 
[2,] 0.1020202  0.2532555 
[3,] 0.1424242  0.2532177 
[4,] 0.2333333  0.2531311 
[5,] 0.3848485  0.2529815 
[6,] 0.6171717  0.2527504 
[7,] 1.0000000  0.2524634
```

and I want to print these two columns in one graph but with different colors. I did this

```
plot(dat1$Y,type="o",col="red")

lines(dat1$X,type="o",col="blue")
```

**UPDATE 1:** After modification I am executing these commands:

```
x_val <- seq(0,7,7)
plot(x_val,dat1$Y,type="o",ylim=c(0.2,0.3),col="red")
plot(x_val,dat1$X,type="o",ylim=c(0,1),col="blue")
```

but I get error as

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

but in the graph Y plot comes correct but the X plot comes like a straight line and not like Y plot. Why is this happening?

Comment: That's because they are on completely different y scales ranges. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to plot them with two different y scales? Take a look [here](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-base:2yaxes) on how to achive this

Comment: @DavidArenburg I did modified my post above but an error is coming.

Comment: What do you need `x_val` for? Your code won't change the output

Comment: @DavidArenburg I did that based on the example shown in the link. I though that putting x coordinate values is required. How should I do it?

Comment: could you upload an image of the graph?

Comment: `length(seq(0,7,7))` equals to `2` :) Pls share your data frame with `dput` and give more details on what kind of plot you would like to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- 1:7
y <- dat1$Y
z <- dat1$X
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.3)  
plot(x, y, type = "o", col = "red", ylab = "dat1$Y") 
par(new = TRUE)
plot(x, z, type = "o", col = "blue", axes = FALSE, bty = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(side=4, at = pretty(range(z)))
mtext("dat1$X", side=4, line=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generating some numbers for a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:7, x = runif(7), y = runif(7))
```

Resulting in:

```
  id         x          y
1  1 0.4622928 0.13871017
2  2 0.9400145 0.98889173
3  3 0.9782264 0.94666823
4  4 0.1174874 0.08243756
5  5 0.4749971 0.51421178
6  6 0.5603327 0.39020347
7  7 0.9040314 0.90573813
```

Melting data for easy plotting:

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df, id.vars = 'id')
```

Then call `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot line plot POC demo]